# How to display image like facebook

Tags: php, image, facebook

i want to display images like facebook find friends page. i dont want to crop an image.  want to reduce size of image.and maintains its actuall appereance.how i can do this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image resize PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3530946/image-resize-php)

Comment: Also [Resize image with PHP, detect longest side, and resize according?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5917433)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend the [IMagick](http://php.net/imagick) extension for PHP since it's light on resources and easy to use. The [GD](http://php.net/gd) extension comes bundled with PHP, but is harder to use and uses a lot of memory.

Here's an example for IMagick:

```
<?php
header('Content-type: image/jpeg');
$image = new Imagick('image.jpg');

$image->thumbnailImage(100, 100, true);

echo $image;
?>
```

Comment: Fine if you have full control of the server, PHP users tend to have controlled hosting, non-standard extensions are tricky.  Fairly normal to have the Image Magick command line utilities installed though, which I often use - but not as efficient/quick as the extension obviously.

Comment: @Deepa: Do you have the IMagick extension installed?

Comment: Then use the GD extension. Here's a resizing example in the manual: http://se2.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresized.php#76648

Answer (score 1):

**i dont want to crop an image. want to reduce size of image.and maintains its actuall appereance.**

If the actual image size is 128*128 pixel you can use

```
<img src="..." height="64px" />
```

"actuall appereance." i think you are talking bout ratio ?

Comment: @saurav this is not what i want. this does not maintain scale of height and width of image

Comment: Note that browser scaling is slightly undesirable generally, as it is often not the best quality and more importantly, means the client is unnecessarily downloading a larger file than needed.

Comment: @Orbling yup you are correct, but if the 128 pixel image is of 25kb, then i think client will not be angry :) ! @Deepa are you sure that it does not work ?

Comment: @Deepa: If you want to preserve the aspect ratio (that is the word for the relative scale of height and width) it can still be done using browser scaling.  Just have to make sure `width` and `height` are scaled appropriately in the HTML, or just fix **one** dimension I think Sourav is suggesting, do not define the other (though that is technically invalid).

Comment: @Sourav: If it's 25KB, probably not.  If it's a 10MP camera shot and you need a 100px thumb, you might get crucified. ;-)

Comment: @saurav i have not fixed size of height and width

Comment: @Orbling "(though that is technically invalid)" it works on all the browser, though have not tried on IE3 :P

Comment: @Orbling if you resize image in PHP the image should be around 25KB [80% sure] of a 128px image

Comment: @Sourav: What works and what is valid in the world of HTML, are two very different things, sadly.

Comment: @Orbling comeon man, look at Facebook, when i did validator.w3  verification there was error, but look at FB, i dont think any body care about such thing ! [i may be wrong]

Comment: @Sourav: Definitely wrong, it causes major hassles if you use invalid code, every last file my company touches has to be totally validated.  There are exceptions, but there are usually important reasons for them.  The only reason a lot of people do not bother, is because a lot of people do not bother - there are a lot of amateur developers out there.  This is part of what makes browsers so difficult to make, as they have to cater for invalid code.

Comment: @Sourav: Your example above is actually a useful feature however, the problem there is that the specification for the language is too tight.  I wonder if `width=""` is legal and achieves the same thing?  Perhaps not, haven't tried yet.